# Calll states, and class methods inside Object.keys().map in render

Tags: loops, render, reactjs

How i can call function and states inside the loop in render -

```
    render(){
        return(
          <div
             {Object.keys(this.state.valueList).map(function (item) {
                return(
                    <Input key={item} list={this.state.disableList} x={this.getPosition(item)} />
                )


             })}
          </div>
}

    getPosition(value){
        .......
    }
```

Still getting error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPosition' of undefined

same with `this.state.disableList`

Comment: Set `this` for callback, pass context as second argument `Object.keys(this.state.valueList).map(function (item) { .... }, this)`

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot ! , write it as answer, i will mark it as correct

Comment: @LukášUnzeitig your <div> below return( ... don't get close, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `this` is not bound and accessible, so to ensure `this` is bound to your component and you can call your function, either use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), or [bind this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html).

I prefer arrow functions, like this

```
<Input key={item} list={this.state.disableList} x={(() => this.getPosition)(item)} />
```

---

As mentioned by @Alexander  T in the comments, here is how you `bind this` to an `iterator` (`map`, `forEach`, etc...)

```
Object.keys(this.state.valueList).map(function (item) { .... }, this)
```